# how to search all fields in a json document

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I currently have many json documents stored in amazon s3 I am looking to build search functionality how do you setup solr/lucene/elasticsearch to search all fields in a json document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, elasticsearch uses exactly the json format, therefore if you send a json document to it, that document is going to be indexed (all fields). You can already search against it using the [`_all` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/all-field/), which is indexed by default and contains all terms coming from all the fields in the json. The limitation of this approach is that you apply the same text analysis, which you can change through [the mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/), to all of the fields in the json, while you might want to do different things depending on the specific field.

Anyway, have a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation/) to know how to setup elasticsearch, and use the [index api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/index_/) to send documents to it. Once you indexed the documents you can use the [search api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/) to execute queries.